# Returned data not showing in source code, How do I select Ajax Loaded Data?

Tags: jquery

I am making a Category Tree Selection for eBay Categories.
I have a select box...

```
<div id="div_firstCat">
    <select id="slct_firstCat" name="slct_firstCat" size="33">
        <option value="353">Antiques</option>
        <option value="550">Art</option> ... and so on..
    </select>
</div>

<div id="div_secondCat"></div>
```

I am using the following JQuery function to post data to my PHP application, which will return another Select box depending on which first category is selected (above).

```
// First Level Categories
    $("#slct_firstCat").change(function(){ // On change of slct_firstCat
    var actionRequested = "AJAX_getCats";  // My personal PHP Identifer
    var url = "index.php";                 // Post to index.php
    var catId = $("#slct_firstCat").val(); // Get the CatID from the select box.

    // Post this data to PHP and return the data into #div_secondCat
    $.post(url, {AJAX_Action: actionRequested, categoryId: catId, categoryLevel: 1},
        function(data){
            $("#div_secondCat").html(data);
           });
    // End of Function getCats
    });
```

The PHP File returns this select box, identical to above but different name.

```
<select id="slct_secondCat" name="slct_secondCat" size="33">
        <option value="353">Sub-Cat of Antiques</option>
        <option value="550">Sub-Cat of Antiques</option> and so on..
</select>
```

Now when I try to get a option value via JQuery from "slct_secondCat" (The select loaded via AJAX), It doesnt get the option value, so I cant navigate further down the cat tree.

This is the JQuery Function for the second category post.

```
// Second Level Categories
    $("#slct_secondCat").change(function(){
    var actionRequested = "AJAX_getCats";
    var url = "index.php";
    var catId = $("#slct_secondCat").val();

    $.post(url, {AJAX_Action: actionRequested, categoryId: catId, categoryLevel: 2},
        function(data){
            $("#div_thirdCat").html(data);
           });
    // End of Function getCats
    });
```

When I look in the source code of the page, after the AJAX loaded data, The div_secondCat doesnt display anything inside the source code, Even though the div has data loaded into it, the JQuery returned data from the post into the div and didnt update the source code of the page.

So Basically, I get categories from my PHP file via eBay web service, I want to navigate to the final category I want and be able to select it via JQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
// Second Level Categories
$("#slct_secondCat").live("change", function(){
```

Also: Clicking "View Page Source" will only show you the original HTML document. You'll need to check in Firebug or Webkit Inspector to see what's really going on in the DOM.

Comment: Awesome. Glad you're up-and-running. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

> When I look in the source code of the page, after the AJAX loaded data

If you're talking about "view source" or similar, that's because it will show you the actual source of the page, not a view of what the DOM *now* looks like. For that, you need a proper debugger. Fortunately, [they're thick on the ground](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/03/no-excuse.html), and free.

Regarding why you're not seeing the `change` event: When do you run your code to hook it up? Because this line:

```
$("#slct_secondCat").change(...
```

...will only hook up the handler if the element *already* exists. If it doesn't, the handler isn't hooked up. You can either call that function to hook it up after your previous ajax call that creates the element is complete, or use [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) (or better yet, [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)).

```
$("#slct_secondCat").live('change', ...
```

or

```
$("#div_secondCat").delegate("#slct_secondCat", 'change', ...
```

(Note in that last one that we're using `div_secondCat` in the initial selector, then calling `delegate` on that.)